# COMException when waiting for a WPF combobox to populate

Tags: wpf, mvvm

So there is another question similar to this but I think this is a little different. Here is a the deal, I am working on an app where there is a series of combo boxes right, the user makes a selection and then the next combo box populates. It works but I see a bunch of these errors.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

I have my items panel template set like this for all of the combo boxes.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VirtualizingItemsPanelTemplate">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Is there anything else I can do to try to not get this error? It seems to be causing a bit of a slow down (I wouldn't quit call it freezing up - that is too string a term) but this screen is going to be super high value in terms of usage and I want to keep it as responsive as possible.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You have the same error message in your qustion 10 times.

Comment: Uhm, well, I see that error whizzing by over and over - that was a sample of what I am seeing. I haven't a clue what is causing it. The list that it is bound to is being refreshed at that point but everything works fine, I just don't want any errors if I can get rid of them.

Comment: You only need to list it once.  Make your question clear, get rid of the extra copies of the error message, also post your code dealing with the listboxes.

Comment: I think it is perfectly fine to list it multiple times.  It illustrates why the app is freezing up.  The exception is occurring a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and from what I have found, the issue is dealing with the Visual Studio Debugger.

Applications that are built and ran separately from the debugger will not experience the delay.

It is a half-solution until Microsoft fixes their debugger/VS.